# raster2pqsql error while importing raster

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, raster2pgsql

I am trying to import tif image into PostgreSQL using the raster2pgsql and I am getting this error

```
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "public"."test" ("rast") VALUES ('01000008000000...
```

PostgreSQL - 15.2, PostGIS 3.3, and running on Ubuntu 20.04. I tried to import the same image on my Windows, and it works perfectly. I reinstalled both pgsql and PostGIS, but still getting this error... Any clues?

```
 raster2pgsql -s 32642 20220527_061148_58_2407_3B_AnalyticMS_SR_8b_clipped.tif public.test | psql -h localhost -p 5434 -U postgres -d postgres -W
```

Comment: Coding questions require sharing codes. Kindly share the code that u have tried.

Comment: What is the exact error? It is truncated.  Can you import a smaller tif to see if it works?